# QTableView Paginate

Tags: c++, qt

I want to view my data in tabular form and i do not want to keep scrolling to view more data,instead i want to paginate.Is pagination possible here?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass QTableView and implement your functionality.
I dont think there is a built-in feature like this.
You may need to subclass some more classes and not only QTableView.